# sublime text html file with inline coffeescript

Tags: html, coffeescript, inline, sublimetext3

How do I get the ST3 HTML package (built in, I believe, to ST3) to recognize an inline CoffeeScript `<script>` tag?

I.e. when using

```
    <script src="../tools/coffee-script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/coffeescript">
        ... CS code ..
    </script>
```

the HTML package should use the CoffeeScript package for editing within the script block (which is compiled by the coffee-script.js library on page-load)

Any solutions for how to have the HTML package recognize CoffeeScript the same way it does JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom .tmLanguage (or edit the existing HTML one) file that will define the 'text/coffeescript' to be have the scope of a coffescript scope.

you can find an example [here.](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/inline-coffeescript-in-html-file/4806/4)

Basicly, what they suggest is that you'll add the following code to your HTML.tmLangugage file:

```
<dict>
    <key>begin</key>
    <string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:script))\b(?=^&gt;]*type *=^&gt;]*text/coffeescript)\b(?!^&gt;]*/&gt;)</string>
    <key>beginCaptures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>punctuation.definition.tag.html</string>
        </dict>
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>entity.name.tag.script.html</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>end</key>
    <string>(?&lt;=&lt;/(script|SCRIPT))(&gt;)(?:\s*\n)?</string>
    <key>endCaptures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>punctuation.definition.tag.html</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>source.coffee.embedded.html</string>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>include</key>
            <string>#tag-stuff</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>begin</key>
            <string>(?&lt;!&lt;/(?:script|SCRIPT))(&gt;)</string>
            <key>captures</key>
            <dict>
                <key>1</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>punctuation.definition.tag.html</string>
                </dict>
                <key>2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>entity.name.tag.script.html</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>end</key>
            <string>(&lt;/)((?i:script))</string>
            <key>patterns</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>include</key>
                    <string>source.coffee</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

That should work alright.